# RSpec Cannot find my Controllers Uninitialized Constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

My rails app recently moved from Rails 3 to Rails 4 and I've been trying to run rspec on individual specs (controllers, models, etc.) and it seems to be having an issue actually locating the object.  For example, when I try to run the following code it errors with an uninitialized constant error.  This seems to be happening for multiple controllers.  I've already tried deleting the rails_helper.rb and spec_helper.rb and running rails generate rspec:install but it doesn't seem to resolve the error.  Why can't it find the controllers?

**What I'm Trying to execute**

```
-> rspec spec/controllers/activity_controller_spec.rb 
/Users/osx_user/rails_projects/tealeaf_rails/ltbweb/spec/controllers/activity_controller_spec.rb:4:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActivitiesController (NameError)
```

**rails_helper.rb**

```
# This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
# Add additional requires below this line. Rails is not loaded until this point!

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, in
# spec/support/ and its subdirectories. Files matching `spec/**/*_spec.rb` are
# run as spec files by default. This means that files in spec/support that end
# in _spec.rb will both be required and run as specs, causing the specs to be
# run twice. It is recommended that you do not name files matching this glob to
# end with _spec.rb. You can configure this pattern with the --pattern
# option on the command line or in ~/.rspec, .rspec or `.rspec-local`.
#
# The following line is provided for convenience purposes. It has the downside
# of increasing the boot-up time by auto-requiring all files in the support
# directory. Alternatively, in the individual `*_spec.rb` files, manually
# require only the support files necessary.
#
# Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

# Checks for pending migrations before tests are run.
# If you are not using ActiveRecord, you can remove this line.
ActiveRecord::Migration.maintain_test_schema!

RSpec.configure do |config|
  # Remove this line if you're not using ActiveRecord or ActiveRecord fixtures
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  # RSpec Rails can automatically mix in different behaviours to your tests
  # based on their file location, for example enabling you to call `get` and
  # `post` in specs under `spec/controllers`.
  #
  # You can disable this behaviour by removing the line below, and instead
  # explicitly tag your specs with their type, e.g.:
  #
  #     RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do
  #       # ...
  #     end
  #
  # The different available types are documented in the features, such as in
  # https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

**spec_helper.rb**

```
# This file was generated by the `rails generate rspec:install` command. Conventionally, all
# specs live under a `spec` directory, which RSpec adds to the `$LOAD_PATH`.
# The generated `.rspec` file contains `--require spec_helper` which will cause this
# file to always be loaded, without a need to explicitly require it in any files.
#
# Given that it is always loaded, you are encouraged to keep this file as
# light-weight as possible. Requiring heavyweight dependencies from this file
# will add to the boot time of your test suite on EVERY test run, even for an
# individual file that may not need all of that loaded. Instead, consider making
# a separate helper file that requires the additional dependencies and performs
# the additional setup, and require it from the spec files that actually need it.
#
# The `.rspec` file also contains a few flags that are not defaults but that
# users commonly want.
#
# See http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-core/RSpec/Core/Configuration
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # rspec-expectations config goes here. You can use an alternate
  # assertion/expectation library such as wrong or the stdlib/minitest
  # assertions if you prefer.
  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|
    # This option will default to `true` in RSpec 4. It makes the `description`
    # and `failure_message` of custom matchers include text for helper methods
    # defined using `chain`, e.g.:
    # be_bigger_than(2).and_smaller_than(4).description
    #   # => "be bigger than 2 and smaller than 4"
    # ...rather than:
    #   # => "be bigger than 2"
    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  # rspec-mocks config goes here. You can use an alternate test double
  # library (such as bogus or mocha) by changing the `mock_with` option here.
  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|
    # Prevents you from mocking or stubbing a method that does not exist on
    # a real object. This is generally recommended, and will default to
    # `true` in RSpec 4.
    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

# The settings below are suggested to provide a good initial experience
# with RSpec, but feel free to customize to your heart's content.
=begin
  # These two settings work together to allow you to limit a spec run
  # to individual examples or groups you care about by tagging them with
  # `:focus` metadata. When nothing is tagged with `:focus`, all examples
  # get run.
  config.filter_run :focus
  config.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  # Limits the available syntax to the non-monkey patched syntax that is recommended.
  # For more details, see:
  #   - http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax
  #   - http://teaisaweso.me/blog/2013/05/27/rspecs-new-message-expectation-syntax/
  #   - http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2014/05/notable-changes-in-rspec-3#new__config_option_to_disable_rspeccore_monkey_patching
  config.disable_monkey_patching!

  # Many RSpec users commonly either run the entire suite or an individual
  # file, and it's useful to allow more verbose output when running an
  # individual spec file.
  if config.files_to_run.one?
    # Use the documentation formatter for detailed output,
    # unless a formatter has already been configured
    # (e.g. via a command-line flag).
    config.default_formatter = 'doc'
  end

  # Print the 10 slowest examples and example groups at the
  # end of the spec run, to help surface which specs are running
  # particularly slow.
  config.profile_examples = 10

  # Run specs in random order to surface order dependencies. If you find an
  # order dependency and want to debug it, you can fix the order by providing
  # the seed, which is printed after each run.
  #     --seed 1234
  config.order = :random

  # Seed global randomization in this process using the `--seed` CLI option.
  # Setting this allows you to use `--seed` to deterministically reproduce
  # test failures related to randomization by passing the same `--seed` value
  # as the one that triggered the failure.
  Kernel.srand config.seed
=end
end
```

Comment: I'd like commentary on the downvote here.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I added

`require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)`

to the spec_helper.rb file and this resolved the error.  I'm not sure why the spec_helper needs this, but I think it has something to do with Rails' ability to locate a file's path relative to another file, and I suspect this was messing up RSpec's ability to find the appropriate controllers, models, etc.

I did some research and found that previously we were on RSpec 2.14 and we're now on 3.2, and I think there may be some differences in the way rspec uses these two files.  In our old spec_helper file we had this line:

`require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)`

Comment: I don't understand why this is not included by default.  Drove me nuts for hours until I found this answer.

Comment: It is included--in rails_helper.rb.  If you update RSpec you need to change your includes at the top of your spec files.

Comment: Does anyone know why that is needed? It feels very strange and just adding it like this with no explanation

Answer (score 22):

I have added

```
--require rails_helper
```

in .rspec in my rails application, it resolves the error.

Answer (score 9):

Ensure `require 'rails_helper'` is at the top of your spec.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you have upgraded rspec.  That require line was moved from spec_helper to the new file rails_helper.  You probably failed to change the line at the top of your spec file to include rails_helper instead of spec_helper.  (note that rails_helper in turn includes spec_helper)

Answer (score 3):

Could it simply be that you're referring to Activit**ies**Controller and yet the controller is defined as Activit**y**Controller.

It says...

> uninitialized constant Activi**ties**Controller

and yet your spec file is called...

> rspec spec/controllers/activi**ty**_controller_spec.rb

Comment: It doesn't look like that's it.  The error message is referencing line 4 in the spec itself, which says `describe ActivitiesController do`.  I believe the plurality of the spec name doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: This simple suggestion helped me, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have my controllers inside of 'api/v1/' so I had to define in the spec file something like:

```
describes Api::V1::ActivitiesController do
```

I hope this can help you ;)